# How create game camera without remove camera coords to each JComponent

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have been creating a 2D camera in Swing. But then I discovered that if I use graphics.translate (to move the origin of coordinates) and set the position of the children using coordinates relative to the start of the world, unexpected behavior occurs:

- In my original program, the JComponents don't redraw when they should.
- In the published mcve, the image is still drawn where it was initially created, as well as being drawn on the correct side and not updating anymore.

The idea would be that, having the coordinates relative to the start of the "world", that the redraw process automatically converts that into coordinates relative to the JPanel.

What would be the correct way to achieve it without directly using the coordinates relative to the JPanel.

**Application.java**

```
package regexlang;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Application extends JFrame{    
    public Application() {
        setSize(800, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        add(new Panel());
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                Application ex = new Application();
                ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

**Panel.java**

```
package regexlang;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private JLabel label;
    
    public Panel() {
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        
        this.label = new JLabel("hola mundo");
        this.label.setBounds(700, 0, 100, 100);
        this.label.setOpaque(true);
        add(this.label);
        
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.translate(-this.x, -this.y);
    }

    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        g.translate(-this.x, -this.y);
        super.paintComponents(g);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Color color = new Color(random.nextInt(256),
                                random.nextInt(256),
                                random.nextInt(256));
        
        this.label.setBackground(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        this.x += 1;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }   
}
```

**Edit** After some more thinking, I have a hypothesis that the coordinates used by swing are calculated before it gets to translate the origin of coordinates with Graphics.translate. I've tried to get around this by overriding the getGraphics method, to no avail (since it doesn't seem to be used much internally).

Comment: Don't override paintComponents().  Don't change properties of a Graphics object directly. These properties will be passed down to all the child components. If you need to change properties then use the `create()` method to create a temporary Graphics instance and then do your custom painting. You will then need to use the `dispose()` method to release the created Graphics instance.

Comment: However, in your case you are not doing any custom painting so there is no need to override paintComponent(...) or use the translate(...) method. Swing automatically calculates child locations relative to the parent panel.

Comment: @camickr thanks for the advice! I'll keep it in mind. However, if by "child components" you mean "direct children", then let's say that's my intention.

Comment: In my original code, if I do custom painting. Regarding the use of translate, the problem is that I don't want it to be calculated "relative to the JPanel", but rather relative to the coordinates of the world.

Comment: *but rather relative to the coordinates of the world.* - no idea what that means since the [mre] has no reference to the "workd", only a single component added to the panel.

Comment: @camickr I'll give you an example, I want to create an object at coordinates 700, relative to the world. But when moving the "camera" 100 pixels, I want the object to be at coordinates 600 relative to the JPanel. Let's say, the coordinates relative to the "world" are always the same, but the ones relative to the camera are not.